# Saving data in text file using chrome packaged app/extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Since Chrome packaged/extensions are only written in HTML5, JavaScript and CSS, I was wondering is there a way to save data in text file without the use of server script language like php? All I need to do is save some variables values into text file when users click on Save Data. So Since I can only use JavaScript, HTML5, is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Is your goal that users have a text file that they can edit/copy/delete on their own outside your program? Or are you just trying to save data that your program can load later on for the user? You said "text file" but it's not clear from your description that that particular solution is needed for your problem.

Comment: I have a client side Chrome packaged app in JavaScript/HTML5. The users enter some parameters that they save in text file to the local folder. Then the user saves that text file to the Google Drive. First I was thinking if I could get something that will save the parameters into text file and by itself be uploaded back to Google Drive since I have using Google Drive as a database. I don't know if that's possible so for now I was wondering if I could get something that will just save the parameters into text file. So when a user click on "save data" the text file should be created.

Comment: Hmmmm, yeah, then you might want to consider the storage API approaches mentioned in answers below. It doesn't appear from your description that the text file is a must-have.

Answer (score 1):

These should help you out... my app saves user creds in Chrome Storage:

```
// init storage
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

// listens for events when storage changes (debug)
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  for(key in changes) {
    var storageChange = changes[key];
    if(debug)
      console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. Old value was: %s, new value is: %s', key, namespace, storageChange.oldValue, storageChange.newValue);
  }
});

function saveStorage() { // saves the current credz to storage
  storage.set({'username':username}, function() {});
  storage.set({'password':password}, function() {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I actually tried this but I am getting an error that says "Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined". I checked online for this error, some people were saying it could be due to old Google chrome but I have 25v and still I am getting this error. Do you have an idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: Have you requested the storage permission in your manifest? If you don't you will see that kind of message. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html) are details on how to use the storage API.

Answer (score 1):

[chrome storage](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html) is likely what you want today, and better yet the upcoming [chrome.syncFileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/syncFileSystem.html). See the [syncfs-editor](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/syncfs-editor) sample.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really require a text file, you can use the HTML5 localStorage API:

```
localStorage.foo = "myData";
//or
localStorage['foobar'] = "moreData";
```

to get the data back:

```
myDataValue = localStorage.foo;
```

Comment: I actually need a text file so that I can keep a record of it in Google Drive. There is one more web app that takes this record from Google Drive. I actually tried this method, I was able to save data and get it back but my main purpose is to save it in text file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the chrome apps codelab yet? Here's a link to the JavaScript version of the storage sync sample: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-codelab/tree/master/lab5_data/javascript/1_storage_sync.